# Virtualbox errors and missing snapshots

Tags: virtualbox, snapshot, vdi

I really hope someone can help me here as otherwise I've lost a lot of files :( I thought I'd move my VDI to my SSD drive to gain better performance. Now it seems to have reverted to it's original state before I've made any changes.

Here is what I have done:

- Copied the vdi over to my SSD Drive
- In Virtual Media Manager attempted to add it as a new disk but got an error about the UUID already being in use. I thought this was because the original disk was still in VMM so I released and removed them (but keeping all the files). The error still appeared and after googling it used VBoxManage to create a new UUID for the disk and added it successfully.
- Then I added the disk successfully and started the VM only to find it had reverted to before my snapshot.

Please can someone tell me what I can do? In the snapshots folder there are still several snapshot vdis one of them 5.6GB which I think is the one with my files on.